# count and distinct count without groupby using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (`testdf`) and would like to get count and distinct count on a column (`memid`) where another column (`booking`/`rental`) is not null or not empty (ie."")

`testdf`:

```
memid   booking  rental
100        Y 
100
120        Y
100        Y       Y
```

Expected result: (for booking column not null/ not empty)

```
count(memid)  count(distinct memid)
      3                      2
```

If it was SQL:

```
Select count(memid), count(distinct memid) from mydf 
where booking is not null and booking!= ""
```

In PySpark:

```
mydf.filter("booking!=''").groupBy('booking').agg(count("patid"), countDistinct("patid"))
```

But I just want the overall counts and not have it grouped by..

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove the `GroupBy` and use `agg` directly.
Like this.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
mydf=mydf.filter("booking!=''").agg(F.count("patid"), F.countDistinct("patid"))
```